# Overriding operator<< for console output doesn't work for member variables

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, iostream, ostream

I have a class MyList that overrides the `<<` operator to be able to log itself to the console:

```
class MyList {
public:
    vector<int> *numbers;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyList& l);
```

Implementation:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, MyList& l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l.numbers->size(); i++) {
        os << l.numbers->at(i);         
    }
    return os;
}
```

In an other class I have a member variable of type MyList and I can't print it to the console. Interestingly a local MyList variable works fine:

```
class A {
public:
    MyList list;
    void someMethod() const;
};
```

Implementation:

```
void A::someMethod() const {
    MyList local;
    // Set up local list.
    cout << "Local:" << local; // OK!
    cout << "Member:" << list; // ERROR!
}
```

**This is the error message:**

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char,
std::__1::char_traits<char>>' and 'const MyList')
```

Xcode's auto-fix recommends to reference `list`:

```
cout << "Member:" << &list;
```

This will compile, but (obviously) it prints the adress of `list` and not my content. I don't understand what the difference is between those two variables in regards to the `<<` operator. Could anybody explain?

Comment: Due to the **missing semicolon** after the definition of class A, it is unlikely that the compiler would get as far as you claim, before emitting some error diagnostic. Is this really your *real code*? And if it isn't, how you think we can infer what you real code is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is your real code, but here's my guess:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyList& l)
//                                 |
//                             note const
```

Either that, or something really dumb like forgetting a trailing `;`:

```
class A {
public:
    MyList list;
    void someMethod();
};  // <------- here
```

Comment: I concur, it's again (most probably) a case of someone believing in telepathy. It woulde be interesting to know what culture they all come from. E.g., Alan Turing, a very intelligent man, [claimed to believe in ESP](http://www.turing.org.uk/philosophy/ex9.html), and he was embedded in the 1940's English culture (my conclusion is that in that culture it was socially necessary or at least very socially convenient to appear to believe in ESP).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Telepathy? What are you talking about?

Comment: @Javap: what you're saying is that the `const` that Luchian showed you made a difference, which means that you *did* have a `const` -- on your method. Not shown in your *presented code*. Next, please post **real code**, because we are not telephaths: we can't see your real code at a distance, we can only see the code that you post here.

Comment: Well, you don't need to be telepathic to tell that the code posted isn't the code producing the error message! For the error message to show up, `something()` must be a `const` member.

Comment: @Dietmar: no, the quoted error message doesn't mention `const`. So with the code obviously not real, there are a host of other possibilites. Including incorrect type for the member.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the error message does say `const MyList`. :)

Comment: @Luchian: oh well. don't foil a good argument & lesson by inconvenient facts!

Comment: Sorry about that. I just tried to remove everything that's not related to my problem and removed too much.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, you omitted a `const` in several places: As it stands, your code should be OK. However, if you have a `const` member function, the members are `const` and you can't bind a non-`const` reference to a `const` object. Thus, output operators are normally declared to take a `const&` as second argument:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, MyList const& l) {
    ...
}
```